# How to add/change the default language?

Tags: default-settings, language

Brand new CiviCRM user here. Currently the default Language in Settings - Localization is English (United States). There are no other language options currently available in the Available Languages section. I would like the default language to be English (Australia), but can't find any information on how to do this. I notice that the Formatting Locale has many language options available, including the one I want. Any assistance appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to load the languages from a separate download file, the localization files. Once these files are in place you will be able to select other languages.

Comment: Thanks. What 'separate download file'? Where is it and how do I access it?

Comment: It depends on CMS. See https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/i18n_l10n/